# Leave application database design

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, entity-relationship, erd

I want to design the database for Leave Application but i am not sure if the design is good or not. Below I had attach the ERD for the database.

[image: ERD]

1) leave_type - this table is to save the type of leave (ex: annual leave, emergency leave)

2) total_leave_per_year - this table is to save the total leave allocate every year (ex: annual leave, 20 days)

3) user_leave_balance - this table is for the current year leave balance for each user (ex: user_id:1, total_leave_per_year_id: 1, leave_balance_days: 10 days)

**I have a few concern for my design:**

1) Is my design is correct

2) Let say I want to allocate the leave balance every year for each user, how to reset the leave_balance every year

Answer (score 0):

It looks you don't have any problem in database design 
for resetting leave balance you can set crone job every year